# JS regex to replace empty lines within SCSS between closing curly brace and opening class/id

Tags: javascript, regex, sass

I am trying to create a regex to replace empty lines between SCSS rulesets. The regex should match from a closing curly brace up to either a class (.) or id (#) and remove any lines. Any empty lines which are not placed between these identifyers should not be affected, including if there is something like a comment in the middle as well.

I have setup a fiddle which can be used to test the below example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9y33cvtg/2/

## Example:

**BEFORE**

```
// START

.test1 {
    background: #FFFFFF;

    .test2 {
        background: #FFFFFF;

        .test3 {
            background: #FFFFFF;
        }
    }
}

.test5 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.test6 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

// Comment

.test7 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

---

**AFTER:**

```
// START

.test1 {
    background: #FFFFFF;

    .test2 {
        background: #FFFFFF;

        .test3 {
            background: #FFFFFF;
        }
    }
}
.test5 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.test6 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

// Comment

.test7 {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

So far I have tried to use the following but it has not worked:

```
str.replace(/\}(.*?)\./g, '')
```

Comment: If you want to remove an *empty* line, why not use `\n` or `\r?\n` in the regex? The `.` does not match neither CR nor LF in JS regex. BTW, you could at least try `\s` to match any whitespace. Besides, CSS parsing with regex cannot be 100% safe. Using some CSS parser would be a good idea.

Comment: I need it to be a bit more specific than any empty line, if there is a comment in the middle or if it's the opening ruleset then the line should stay. This can be seen in the example, cheers

Comment: Ok, try [`.replace(/^}$\s+^\.\b/g, '}\n.')`](https://regex101.com/r/53xNry/2) - this will only work for those cases when the CSS file is formatted well - the closing `}` is the single char on a line and the next CSS class dot is the first char on a line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't seem to work however: https://jsfiddle.net/9y33cvtg/

Comment: You did not use my regex from the fiddle (I forgot to add `m` modifier from it in my comment.). It was [`.replace(/^}$\s+^\.\b/gm, '}\n.')`](https://jsfiddle.net/9y33cvtg/1/). Without `m`, `^` matches the start of a string, not the start of a line.

Comment: The multiline modifier made the difference, this is now working, do you want to add this in an answer or should I answer the question? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing CSS files should be done with dedicated libraries.

The following solution is only going to do the following: it will detect a line that equals `}` followed with 1 or more whitespace chars up to a line that starts with a dot. Use it at your own risk.

```
.replace(/^}$\s+^\.\b/gm, '}\n.')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/53xNry/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to the `m` modifier)
- `}` - a `}`
- `$` - end of a line
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `^` - start of a line
- `\.` - a dot (note: if you want to make sure it is followed with some word char, you may use `\b` or even `\w`)

Below is a JS demo:

```js
var str = document.querySelector('.string').innerText;
var output = document.querySelector('.output');

output.innerText = str.replace(/^}$\s+^\.\b/gm, '}\n.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Input:</strong>
<pre class="string">
// START

.test1 {
 background: #FFFFFF;

 .test2 {
  background: #FFFFFF;

  .test3 {
   background: #FFFFFF;
  }
 }
}

.test5 {
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

.test6 {
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

// Comment

.test7 {
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
</pre>

<br>
<strong>Output:</strong>
<pre class="output">
</pre>
```

Comment: Just realised this doesn't work for nested rules in SCSS, guess the } isn't the start of the line? https://jsfiddle.net/9y33cvtg/3/

Comment: Try [`.replace(/^([^\S\r\n]*)\}\s+^([^\S\r\n]*)\./gm, '$1}\n$2.')`](https://regex101.com/r/OHe4qq/1). If that is going to complicate further, please take my advice and start using some CSS parser.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to catch line break like this :

```
output.innerText = str.replace(/^}[\r\n]{2,}(?!\/\/)/gm, '}\n');
```

it seems to works, tell me if it solve your problem

Comment: It won't work because it will remove empty lines before comments.

Comment: Ok i just Edit my post, tell me if it's working for you